# Downvote on outdated answers - desired or counterproductive?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, old-questions

On this question: [Is there a legal way to get D&D 5e core rulebook PDFs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47655/is-there-a-legal-way-to-get-dd-5e-core-rulebook-pdfs)

After the OP added a bounty, I noticed the accepted answer was out of date. I decided to edit that in as a note at the top of the answer. The answer has now attracted a downvote. I'm a bit sad/guilty about that, as I think the answer is still useful, and might still be proven correct in the long term when there is more news on the subject. My note was intended to help someone finding the answer to better notice the hiatus on D&D 5 digital content.

Is there a way I could of brought attention to the outdated content without attracting downvotes, beyond "Please don't downvote." (Generally I find those to be vote bait on low-quality questions and answers)?

Is there a better way in general to handle information like this going out of date (OP has offered bounty, I tried to add "helpful" edit)?

Comment: Note this is only one downvote, and nothing in the scheme of things. It just got me thinking "should I have done this?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of editing I would have left a comment to give the OP a chance to fix and/or add additional info.

Downvoting posts that are not (longer) correct is perfectly OK, that is where downvotes are for.

You would serve that question and the community better if you provide an answer to that question that would be correct today. Maybe the OP of the question might realize that and mark your answer as correct instead of the current answer.

Don't feel sorry for a post. Posts don't have feelings. Voting shouldn't be taken personally.

Answer (score 3):

Most answers to most questions on most SE sites will eventually become out of date.  The world moves on.  Some, of course, much faster than others.

If an obsolete answer has a respectable score, downvoting it will have marginal effect.  Newcomers will still see an upvoted answer.

Leaving a comment on the answer, stating why it has become obsolete will have more impact on others who are seeking an answer to the question.

That doesn't mean that you *shouldn't* downvote.  That remains a matter of choice.